# Class inter-dependence problems

Tags: c++, class, dependencies

Hey so I have three 2 classes: Screen, and Sprite : that depend on each other so if i define one i can not implement the second class to be defined into it as it has not been definded yet! Is there any simple solution to this that does not require a lot of re-coding?

Heres each class definition (Map is also a class):

the Sprite Class: move() wont work without the Screen Class definition....

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////    Sprite Class    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Sprite
{
public:
///////////////////// Get and SET all the privates  ///////
    Sprite(){};
    Sprite(string a_name, char a_symbol, float a_health){
        _name = a_name;
        _symbol = a_symbol;
        _health = a_health;};

    char get_symbol() {return _symbol;};
    void set_symbol(char _sym) {_symbol = _sym;};

    float get_health() {return _health;};
    void set_health(float _numb) {_health = _numb;};
    void add_health (float _numb) {_health += _numb;};

    string get_name() {return _name;};
    string set_name(string _aName) {_name = _aName;};

    int* get_location(){return _location;};
    void set_location(int X, int Y) {
        _location[0] = X;
        _location[1] = Y;};

////////////////////////////////    Move    ////////////
//            WONT WORK UNTIL UNLESS SCEEN CLASS IS DEFINED BEFORE IT
    bool move(Screen screen,int X, int Y) 
    {
        bool OK = true;
    ////////////////////// check whats already there /////
        char newLoc = screen.get_contents(_location[1]+Y,_location[0]+X);
        if (newLoc == '|' || '/' || '_' || '=' || 'X' || 'x' )
            OK = false;


        if (OK == true)
        {
        _location[0] += X;
        _location[1] += Y;
        return true;
        }
        else
        return false;
    };
private:
    string _name;
    char _symbol;
    float _health;
    int _location[2];
};
```

And the screen class: (the sprite overloaded insert function won't work without Sprite def.

```
/////////////////////////   SCREEN CLASS        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Screen
{
private:
///////////////////////////////////////////     Screen Variables ///////////////
    string _name;
    vector <string> _contents;

public:
    Screen(string name){_name = name;
                        _contents.resize(24);};
    ~Screen(){};

////////////////////////////////////////////    Get contents    ///////////////////////////
    string get_contents(int Y) {return _contents[Y];};
    char get_contents(int X, int Y) {return _contents[Y][X];};

////////////////////////////////////////////    Display (1 FPS) ///////////////////////////
    void Display(int numbRefreshes)                                                      //
    {                                                                                    //
        for(int t = 0; numbRefreshes > t;)                                               //
    {                                                                                    //
        UL_2 = GetTickCount()+overSec-UL_1; // Get Time in Milliseconds since start      //

        // GATE TO GETTING INTO THE DISPLAY FUNCTION (every 1 sec)
        if (UL_2 >= 1000)                                                                //
        {                                                                                //
            overSec += 1000 - UL_2;                                                      //
        //    Wait another second before update (1000 milliseconds)                      //
            UL_1+=1000;                                                                  //
            UL_3+= 1;                                                                    //
            char UL_3_string[6];                                                         //
            itoa(UL_3, UL_3_string, 10);                                                 //
        //    Tell the for loop 1 render is complete                                   (/////)
            t+=1;                                   //                                  (///)
        //    Update the time counter                                                    (/)
            int B = sizeof(UL_3_string);            //                                    |
            for(int I = 0; I < sizeof(UL_3_string); I++)
            Screen::Insert(UL_3_string[I], 38+I, 22);

        ///////////////////  Draw each line of the Screen
            for (unsigned int I = 0; I < _contents.size(); I++)
        {
            cout << _contents[I];
        }
        ////////////////    draw any empty lines   NOT WORKING WTF???????
            for(int emptyLines = 24-_contents.size(); emptyLines > 0; emptyLines--)
            {
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    };
///////////////////////////////////////////     Insert  ////////////////////////
    /////////////////// map
    bool Insert(Map& _map)
    {
        for (unsigned int I = 0; I<_map.getContents().size();I++)
        {
            _contents[I] = _map.getContents()[I];
        }
        return true;
    };
    /////////////////// string
        bool Insert(string _string, int Y)
    {
        _contents[Y] = _string;
        return true;
    };
        ///////////////////// char
    bool Insert(char _char, int X, int Y)
    {
        _contents[Y][X] = _char;
        return true;
    };
        ////////////////////  sprite
    bool Insert(Sprite& _sprite)
    {
        _contents[_sprite.get_location()[0]][_sprite.get_location()[1]] = _sprite.get_symbol();     
    };

};
```

Screen theScreen("theScreen");

**Thanks for any help!! =)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would redesign - I can't see why a sprite needs to know about a screen. And what is this:

```
  if (newLoc == '|' || '/' || '_' || '=' || 'X' || 'x' )
```

supposed to be doing? That is not how you test things in C++.

Other problems - don't pass strings by value, pass them as const references, and don't begin names with underscores.

Comment: Beginning names with underscores is allowed; it's only names that begin with double-underscores that can get you into trouble (in particular, potential namespace clashes with compiler-specific tokens).  As far as whether or not it's good style, that's debatable -- but I find it useful as a way to make it obvious which names are member variables (because m_ as a prefix is too wordy ;^))

Comment: @Jeremy I suggest you take another look at the C++ Standard. Names that begin with a single underscore and anything else are reserved at the global scope. Names that begin with a single underscore and an uppercase letter are reserved at all scopes. Names that contain (not just begin with) a double underscore are reserved at all scopes.

Answer (score 0):

First, split your classes to .h files and .cpp files, then use forward declaration (google for it, I can't post link). There are a few other errors in your code, you might like Bjarne Stroustrup's book "Language c++"